# Strange has_many :through issue with adding objects to a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

*Bounty of $25 for the first working solution.*

I'm seeing a really weird has_many :through problem with ActiveRecord.

With these classes:

```
create_table :numbers do |t|
  t.string :phone_number
end
create_table :call_lists do |t|
  t.string :type
  t.string :name
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :county_id
  t.integer :state_id
end
create_table :call_list_memberships do |t|
  t.integer :call_list_id
  t.integer :number_id
end

class CallList < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :call_list_memberships, :autosave => true
  has_many :numbers, :through => :call_list_memberships, :autosave => true
  belongs_to :user
end

class PoliticalDistrict < CallList
end

class CallListMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :call_list
  belongs_to :number
end

class Number < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :phone_number
  has_many :call_list_memberships
  has_many :call_lists, :through => :call_list_memberships
end
```

I get this behaviour:

```
>> p1 = PoliticalDistrict.first
=> #<PoliticalDistrict id: 2, type: "PoliticalDistrict", name: "Random political district", user_id: nil, county_id: nil, state_id: nil>
>> p1.numbers
=> []
>> p1.call_list_memberships
=> []
>> n1 = Number.first
=> #<Number id: 1, phone_number: "07921088939">
>> p1.numbers << n1
=> [#<Number id: 1, phone_number: "07921088939">]
>> p1.numbers
=> [#<Number id: 1, phone_number: "07921088939">]
>> p1.call_list_memberships
=> [#<CallListMembership id: 6, call_list_id: 2, number_id: nil>, #<CallListMembership id: 6, call_list_id: 2, number_id: nil>]
>> p1.save
=> true
```

Adding an object to the :through collection appears to add two items to the root association, both missing the ID of the object added.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

*Edit:* Even this doesn't work:

```
>> pd2.call_list_memberships.create :number => Number.first
=> #<CallListMembership call_list_id: 2, number_id: nil>
>> Number.first
=> #<Number id: 1, phone_number: "07921088939">
>> pd2.call_list_memberships
=> [#<CallListMembership call_list_id: 2, number_id: nil>]
```

Comment: Not a solution, but you should add `create_table :call_list_memberships, :id => false do |t|`

Comment: Just to note that I've eliminated the class name Number (tried PhoneNumber) and the STI PoliticalDistrict as contributory to this issue.

Comment: Zabba, you're quite right, but removing the id from CallListMemberships now results in three records being created, which makes even less sense.

Comment: The autosave is also not part of the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after a long and rather frustrating search for the answer to this, I finally tracked down the issue and it's a damned embarrassing one.

I was using the following dynamic attr_accesssible code in an initializer:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible
  attr_accessor :accessible

  private

  def mass_assignment_authorizer
    if accessible == :all
      self.class.protected_attributes
    else
      super + (accessible || [])
    end
  end
end
```

Which I had conveniently forgotten about and which caused number_id to be inaccessible (thanks to the empty attr_accessible call).

Comment: Damn embarrassing is right! I just spent 15 minutes trying to figure this one out myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed strange behavior. I'm not sure if it is related only to IRB, or to ActiveRecord itself. You'll note that the association is being saved to the database correctly, but the results of IRB calls on the association counts are wrong. Using your example:

```
>> p1.call_list_memberships
=> [#<CallListMembership id: 6, call_list_id: 2, number_id: nil>, #<CallListMembership id: 6, call_list_id: 2, number_id: nil>]
>> p1.save
>> p1.call_list_memberships.length
=> 2 # Huh?
>> p1.call_list_memberships.size
=> 2 # Wtf?
>> p1.call_list_memberships.count
=> 1 # That's more like it
>> p1.reload # refresh the data
>> p1.call_list_memberships.length
=> 1 # now the associations are correct
>> p1.call_list_memberships.size
=> 1
```

What's more odd is it repeats the join table row in the association -- check the object id's of the two CallListMemberships and you'll see they are the same.

**EDIT**

Creating the association using the join table appears to avoid this problem:

```
>> p1=PoliticalDistrict.create(:name=>"Sample")
=> #<PoliticalDistrict id: 1, type: "PoliticalDistrict", name: "Sample", user_id: nil, county_id: nil, state_id: nil, created_at: "2010-11-14 21:33:09", updated_at: "2010-11-14 21:33:09"> 
>> n1=Number.create(:phone_number=>"123")
=> #<Number id: 1, phone_number: "123", created_at: "2010-11-14 21:33:22", updated_at: "2010-11-14 21:33:22"> 
>> p1.call_list_memberships.create(:number=>n1)
=> #<CallListMembership id: 1, call_list_id: 1, number_id: 1, created_at: "2010-11-14 21:33:39", updated_at: "2010-11-14 21:33:39"> 
>> p1.call_list_memberships
=> [#<CallListMembership id: 1, call_list_id: 1, number_id: 1, created_at: "2010-11-14 21:33:39", updated_at: "2010-11-14 21:33:39">] 
>> p1.call_list_memberships.length
=> 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, records are not being saved to the database correctly. Doing p1.call_list_memberships.first.number returns nil

Comment: btw I tried this on Ruby 1.8.7 / Rails 2.3.8 and the behavior is different. On Ruby 1.9.2 / Rails 3.0.1 I see the duplicated `CallListMembership`, but calling `p1.reload` corrects the apparent duplication, and the DB has all the correct rows.

Comment: I still get incorrect DB rows, even after a reload. I'm using REE 1.8.7 / Rails 3.0.1. I'll test it with 1.9.2.

Comment: The duplication is removed after a reload on both 1.8.7 and 1.9.2, but the records in the DB are consistently wrong. What DB were you testing against there? I'm using SQLite3.

Comment: Also SQLite3. What gets written to the DB? Everything looks jake on my end.

Comment: The number_id column is all NULL. I don't understand what is different. Would you mind throwing up your test app as a gist or something so I can eliminate app vs environment?

Comment: Will do, once github comes back up from maintenance. Maybe it's REE? Sure looks like a bug in ActiveRecord, maybe behaving differently on different versions.

Comment: I'm using stock 1.9.2, which doesn't make sense. I don't understand how such a common thing could be so broken... Surely everyone using rails 3 will have hit this?

Comment: Unless the DB problem only crops up in your configuration. What I'm seeing is fairly innocuous bug -- it's only an issue if you look at the `length` of the association. And reloading resets everything to normal. btw did you see the same null ID being written when doing `call_list_memberships.create`?

Comment: Yes I did. I even see this: >> p1.call_list_memberships.create :number_id => n1.id
=> #<CallListMembership call_list_id: 5, number_id: nil>

Comment: I upped the app to https://github.com/zetetic/has_many_through_bug. Failing test is in spec/models/call_list_membership_spec.rb.

Comment: Yep, it's a bug, and fixed in the master branch according to this: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/93c9f4a942c622ecbe8d46ab4838bd072aef9fc0

(At least so far as the length issue is concerned -- not sure if it also fixes your null id problem...)

Lighthouse ticket: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/5968-size-of-through-association-is-not-correct-after-adding-a-has_many-association

Comment: Thanks for that Tom, I don't have the same problem with your test app. I'll post back when I discover the issue in my app.

Comment: zetetic: please PM me with a PayPal address for the bounty.